# Convert ISO 8061 to YYYY/MM/DD?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have this ISO 8061 `2017-05-03T06:31:46.687123+00:00` which I want to convert it to `YYYY-MM-DD` using D3. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Since your question is on how to do it with `d3.js` I would include it in the title for the other users that will see it in the future.

Comment: @tgogos No, including tags into the tilte is frowned upon on SO: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles.

Comment: @altocumulus thanks, good to know that. My thought was that it would be useful to read something like "How to convert ISO 8061 to YYYY/MM/DD with d3.js? when you are navigating in SO.

Answer (score 2):

check out momentjs and specifically the format function: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

You can then write something like:

```
moment("2017-05-03T06:31:46.687123+00:00").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to use `d3.js`... be careful with the version you are using because there has been a small change to the name of the function:

- with v.3.4.11 use `d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")`
- with v.4.9.1 use `d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d")`

### 3.4.11

```js
your_date = new Date('2017-05-03T06:31:46.687123+00:00')

var formatTime = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
new_date = formatTime( your_date ); // 2017-05-03

console.log(new_date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

### 4.9.1

```js
your_date = new Date('2017-05-03T06:31:46.687123+00:00')

var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d");
new_date = formatTime( your_date ); // 2017-05-03

console.log(new_date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this code will work but i didnt test it yet can you test it and give me a feedback please

```js
date = new Date('2017-05-03T06:31:46.687123+00:00');
year = date.getFullYear();
month = date.getMonth() + 1;
dt = date.getDate();

if (dt < 10) {
  dt = '0' + dt;
}
if (month < 10) {
  month = '0' + month;
}

console.log(year + '-' + month + '-' + dt);
```

you can also crop the date

```
dat.toISOString().substring(0, 10)
```

Comment: You can use the `html / css / js snippet` icon where you can add / test your code directly

Answer (score 0):

When I found this library - https://date-fns.org/ I prefer it instead of moment.js. Date-fns is modular, and your could import only one method. This allows significantly reduced bundle size in compare with not modular moment.js:

```
import format from 'date-fns/format';
format('2017-05-03T06:31:46.687123+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```